# how to set layer switching on osm map in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

I have the following code containing two layers with markers, when trying to implement a transition through the LayerManager the class is missing

```
// Create a list to hold your markers
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<>();


// Add some markers to the list
items.add(new OverlayItem("marker1 ", "sth " +"sth2", new GeoPoint(54.73808331990483, 55.97157451178393)));
items.add(new OverlayItem("Marker 2", "This is the second marker", new GeoPoint(54.71323629153077, 55.993348227111085)));
items.add(new OverlayItem("Marker 3", "This is the third marker", new GeoPoint(54.728460008222974, 55.946710455967626)));

// Create an ItemizedOverlayWithFocus to manage and display your markers
ItemizedOverlayWithFocus overlay;
overlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<>(this, items, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<>() @Override
  public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
  // Assuming the OverlayItem object has been created and added to an ArrayList<OverlayItem> items
   String title = item.getTitle();
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, duration).show();

   return true;}

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
   String snippet = item.getSnippet();
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), snippet, duration).show();
   return true;}}
);

// Add the overlay to your map controller

mapView.getOverlayManager().add(overlay);

ArrayList<OverlayItem> concert = new ArrayList<>();

// Add some markers to the list
concert.add(new OverlayItem("concert 1", "This is the first marker", new GeoPoint(54.72568197320434, 55.9441373824082)));
concert.add(new OverlayItem("concert 2", "This is the second marker", new GeoPoint(54.72515454700825, 56.0299419042602)));
concert.add(new OverlayItem("concert 3", "This is the third marker", new GeoPoint(54.77245098808131, 56.05960561313011)));

// Create an ItemizedOverlayWithFocus to manage and display your markers
ItemizedOverlayWithFocus overlays;
overlays = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<>(this, context concert,new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<>() {
 @Override
 public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
 // Assuming the OverlayItem object has been created and added to an ArrayList<OverlayItem> items
   String title = item.getTitle();
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, duration).show();

   return true;}

 @Override
 public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
  String snippet = item.getSnippet();
  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), snippet, duration).show();
  return true;}}
);

// Add the overlay to your map controller
mapView.getOverlayManager().add(overlays);
```

used mapView.getOverlayManager().add(layer2Overlay);
also tried to use LayerManager layerManager = new LayerManager() but got error "Cannot resolve method 'add' in 'LayerManager'"